# SSLProtocol: Illegal protocol 'TLSv1.1' in linux

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, redhat, ssl-certificate, ssl-certificate-renewal

I know u think this a duplicate question but hear me out first. I am not able to find the answer with a system with same conf as min so here is my server conf:

Red Hat 4.1.2-44
CentOS release 5
OpenSSL 1.0.2a
Server version: Apache/2.2.3

I am having protocol issue when I installed a new SSL certificate.I found out that I had TLSv1 enabled. I then looked at an article(link: https://www.leaderssl.com/news/471-how-to-disable-outdated-versions-of-ssl-tls-in-apache) to try to disable TLSv1. I have tried number off possible solutions but I am getting either `Illegal protocol 'TLSv1.1' in linux` error or `No SSL protocols available [hint: SSLProtocol]`

I get `Illegal protocol 'TLSv1.1' when restart command (service httpd restart)  fails after I change SSL protocol to` SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1`)
[image]

and when I apply the SSL protocol: `SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3`, the server restarts successfully but I get the error in the error log of httpd saying `No SSL protocols available [hint: SSLProtocol]`

Comment: What command do you run when you get the error message?

Comment: @TeroKilkanen  I have updated my question. Thanks for your help

Comment: Exactly what Linux distribution is this?

Comment: @MichaelHampton Sorry, I forgot to add. It is CentOS release 5

Answer (score 2):

CentOS 5 is several years past end of life (March 2017) and will never support TLS 1.1 or higher, not even if you attempt to replace critical system libraries as someone seems to have done with this system.

This system should have been upgraded several years ago. It can no longer be postponed. If you want support for TLS 1.1 and higher, you need to upgrade to a currently supported CentOS release (7 or 8, preferred 8).

Comment: Thanks, I know that the server is past end of life. The migration to a new server is underway but due to this error, our other services have stopped. Is there a workaround that can hold up for a few days?

Comment: @DadyByte You could have already had the new system up and your web site running! It doesn't take days, maybe hours or even less than an hour depending on the nature of your web site. Don't make any more excuses.

Answer (score 0):

WARNING: AWFUL HACK APPROACHING

I'm very surprised you have OpenSSL 1.0.2a. The one test VM I have archived with CentOS 5.6 has 1.0.1e and rpmfind shows the same for 6.10, so I wouldn't expect any 5 to have higher. However, *both* 1.0.1 and 1.0.2 implement(ed) TLSv1.1 and TLSv1.2; it is your way-old Apache version that doesn't know how to *configure* them in OpenSSL. So:

- specify `SSLProtocols all -SSLv3 -TLSv1`
- make sure `SSLCiphers` disables all SSLv2 ciphersuites. The `/etc/ssl/conf.d/ssl.conf` in my `mod_ssl` package, which is 2.2.15 (higher than yours if it's in sync with the rest of Apache), already has `!SSLv2` among several 'deletes', but if yours didn't, or it has been removed/changed/replaced in your configuration, add it

As a result of this combination, Apache *thinks* there is a protocol enabled, namely SSLv2, but because the ciphersuites for SSLv2 are disjoint from those for higher protocols, the ciphersuite setting prevents any SSLv2 handshake from actually succeeding, thus handling any insanely stupid clients or (more important) security scanners and auditors. SSLv3 and TLSv1.0 are disabled as specified, and TLSv1.1 and TLSv1.2 (both) remain enabled because your Apache didn't (and couldn't) disable them. Works when tested on a copy of my abovementioned archive VM.

Do NOT use `SSLProtocols SSLv2` as an 'abbreviation'. I'm not sure, but that might lead mod_ssl to use the specific SSLv2 method (i.e. function) rather than the the generic method (misleadingly named SSLv23 in those versions of OpenSSL; in 1.1.x it was finally fixed to TLS_*method) with 'option' flags. You absolutely need the latter.

That said, I agree with Michael: replace this system ASAP

Comment: Thanks dave, I tested the same on other rhel 5 server which I had there it is working, I got to know from the SSL certificate vendor that my protocols are fine but the issue is with cipher suite. what I am not able to understand is then how it was working before I renewed the certificate?